# Can someone help me figure out this class from documentation?

Tags: sockets, documentation, ipc, wt

I have no experience with sockets and I need to implement a process that notifies a user interface of inputs from another process that takes his values from stdin.
[This is the class' documentation](http://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt/doc/reference/html/classWt_1_1WSocketNotifier.html), what should the socket parameter be? It's just an int, is it a handle?
I was told it doesn't play nice with boost.asio.
Can you guys help me write a command prompt program that accepts an int from stdin and sends it to my UI? I just need the sending/receiving code.

Comment: btw, your question might get more answers on the WT forum.

Comment: Not really. It takes them a while to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it's expecting to receive the socket handle (int). I suggest you get to know winsock.

Also, googling for the above class + example yields some good results.

Comment: Yeh figured out this much. But how will it look like? Should I just google?